# How do I achieve these results?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop

I can't find the exact original, but I have attached an image identical to the original.

Edit: https://m.flickr.com/#/photos/jujug/18613887401/in/set-72157653841277990/

Originalish:
https://m.flickr.com/#/photos/ypspotter32/20353487946/in/favorites-125094039@N08/

Getting the original image is next to impossible. However the image I proved is about 95% like the original detail and colour wish, excluding the location.

Tip: to save the images download the whole page and then copy the image from the files. This only applies to the first link which has download disabled. The last link will have a download button.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you want to reproduce ? Is it colors, vignetting, angle of view,.. ?

Comment: The colours and vignetting

Comment: It seems to me those are post-processing effects. I would play with contrast, vibrance and saturation. Same with vignetting. What have you tried to recreate those effects ? You tagged "Lightroom", so with this software I think you have all you need to do it.

Comment: It was made in lightroom and Photoshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run my favourite image analysis tools on your image but it seems the effects you are looking for are post-processing effects (no obvious use of filters).

For the colors, you will probably get something very similar with some contrast adjustment and by playing with saturation and vibrance.

Same thing for the vignetting, the tools of your favorite software (you mentioned Lightroom) will get it done.

Comment: Thank you I will try that. What image analysis program was this?

Comment: Mostly homemade Matlab programs to reveal post-processing effects and detect image alteration. But most of the time (like in your case) just looking at the picture and eventually its histogramm is enough :)